# Why does Spark SQL require double percent symbols for like conditions?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

When I am using a `like` condition in Spark SQL, it seems that it requires the use of 2 percent symbols `%%`.

However, I could not find any documentation on this in the Spark SQL docs. I am curious as to why my set-up might be causing this requirement.
https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-like.html

Example data

**product_table**

| id | product_type | region | location | measurement |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 43635665 | ORANGE - Blood Orange | EU | FRA | 30.5 |
| 78960788 | APPLE GrannySmith | NA | USA | 16.0 |
| 12312343 | APPLE [Organic Washington] | NA | CAN | 7.1 |
| 67867634 | ORANGE, NavelOrange | NA | MEX | 88.4 |

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

APP_NAME = "Product: Fruit Template"
SPARK_CONF = [
    ("spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors", "5"),
    ("spark.executor.memory", "10g"),
    ("spark.executor.cores", "4"),
    ("spark.executor.memoryOverhead", "2000"),
] 

spark_conf = pyspark.SparkConf()
spark_conf.setAppName(APP_NAME)
spark_conf.setAll(SPARK_CONF)

sc = pyspark.SparkContext(conf=spark_conf)
spark = pyspark.sql.SparkSession(sc)

def sql(query):
    return spark.sql(query)

df = sql("""
SELECT *
FROM product_table
""")
```

this returns data

```
df.filter(F.col("product_type").like("ORANGE%%")).show()
```

whereas this returns an empty dataframe

```
df.filter(F.col("product_type").like("ORANGE%")).show()
```

Maybe worth noting, the same issue happens when the `LIKE` condition is used in the SQL string

this returns data

```
df_new = sql("""
SELECT *
FROM product_table
WHERE product_type like 'ORANGE%%'
""")

df_new.show()
```

whereas this returns an empty dataframe

```
df_new = sql("""
SELECT *
FROM product_table
WHERE product_type like 'ORANGE%'
""")

df_new.show()
```

Comment: i am not able to reproduce this..i am getting data using the single percent as normal
`df.filter(F.col("product_type").like("ORANGE%")).show(truncate=False)`

Comment: What type of database did you store the table, I used a hive DB. Which spark version are you using?

Comment: I just created the dataframe manually..i posted below

Comment: My example is querying a stored table, `product_table`. I recently learned that this table is partitioned on the `product_type` column. So the extra `% ` that I require in my query is probably related to the overall tech stack, rather than directly being a spark-sql or pyspark question. Adding tags to the post

Answer (score 1):

i am using `PySpark Version: 2.3.2`.

```
conf = (SparkConf()
    .set("spark.executor.instances", "24")
    .set("spark.executor.cores", "5")
    .set("spark.executor.memory", "33g")
    .set("spark.driver.memory", "55g")
    .set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "10g")
    .set("spark.sql.catalogImplementation", "hive")
    .set("mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version", "2")
)

spark = (
    SparkSession.builder.appName("default")
    .enableHiveSupport()
    .config(conf=conf)
    .getOrCreate()
)

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('43635665','ORANGE - Blood Orange'),
     ('78960788','APPLE GrannySmith'),
     ('12312343','APPLE [Organic Washington'),
     ('67867634','ORANGE, NavelOrange')],
    ['id', 'product_type'])

df.createOrReplaceTempView("product_table")

def sql(query):
    print(query)
    return spark.sql(query)

df2 = sql("""
SELECT *
FROM product_table
""")
df2.filter(F.col("product_type").like("ORANGE%")).show(truncate=False)
```